# How do I divide a matrix into a series of bins based on polar coordinates

Tags: arrays, coordinates, fft, bin

I'm trying to write a program in Octave/Matlab that aims to take an image, perform the 2D Fast Fourier Transform on that image, and then take the FFT data and divide it into a series of bins from which the mean FFT intensity can be calculated. These bins need to calculate the intensity of the fourier spectrum for each 5 degree segment of that spectrum:

i.e. Imagine a 500x500 array, then divide it into 72 equal slices (like a slicing a pizza) with each slice being 5 degrees apart. These slices then form the bins and an average of the values within them is calculated.

I understand that to produce this, I must convert the Cartesian coordinates of the resultant FFT into Polar coordinates, so that I can calculate the bins using values of theta. In addition, to slice the array up like a pizza, the Polar coordinates must originate at the center of the image. I have a good idea how to do this, but I am stuck on how to divide the array up into the bins once I have completed this.

Can anyone help? Assuming that this explanation makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not completely clear.

But I assume you mean polar coordinates *in the fourier domain*, in which case you can get the angle of each point from something like `atan2(f_y, f_x)` where `f_y` and `f_x` are the y and x coordinates in the fourier domain. With FFTs, these are usually related to the array index by the ordering

```
f = [0, 1, 2, ..., n/2-1, -n/2, ..., -1]
```

For matlab, see also [fftshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fftshift.html)